# Magento audit in custom design

Tags: magento

Recently we had a magento audit and one of their suggestion as follows:

**Location:**

`app/design/frontend/enterprise/mytheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml:59`,

```
Type: Maintainability
Name: Hardcoded Value
Priority: Low
Description: Hardcoding values like product type code, store id, file name, credentials, etc. may cause serious issues during future upgrades or porting.

Recommendation: Such values can be stored in class constants or in the system configuration for the best flexibility.
```

Example:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getSomeSku()
```

If we add custom code in custom theme, will that affect during upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Custom vs. hard-coded

The issue here is not the fact that the code is custom. It's the fact that the code is not upgrade-safe.

### Why hard-coding is bad

Hard-coded values aren't easily accessible for future changes. Updates may perform unexpected actions and you may end up with a broken page because of it.

The values themselves can become obsolete if an upgrade procedure re-creates an object (deletes and saves) and the object ID changes because of it.

### Upgrade-path

The topics approached by an audit team are intended to help you to achieve an automated upgrade-path. Meaning that if you would respect all of those suggestions they made running your upgrade should be clean and error-less. Otherwise your debugging day has just arrived.